# Need help with getting a direction vector between two given points

Tags: libgdx, vector, linear-algebra

I need to find the angle of rotation from a bullet traveling from point A to point B, like in my attached diagram. I tried searching, but I got a little lost in which exact formula to use.

I want to find the direction of a bullet, expressed as a vector with X and Y coordinates.

[image: Points A and B are both points on a 2D grid.]

Comment: Errr... `B - A`?

Comment: Do you need an angle or a vector?

Comment: I need a vector i did add that too my question a while back

Comment: basically i need the Direction as a vector of the bullet leaving point A

Comment: if B was exactly below A then the Direction Vector would be (0,-1) and if it was directly to the right of it the vector for direction would be (1,0) but what if point B is at an irregular position? how i work it out?

Comment: When you edit a question, don't just _add_, modify the content to reflect what you actually need, specially when there are no answers yet :) In this case, you should edit the title as well to reflect the fact that you don't need an angle, but a vector!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53538/discussion-between-alexandre-vaillancourt-and-super-megabrobro).

Comment: This similar to [How to calculate a path to the mouse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39770924/how-to-calculate-a-path-to-the-mouse/39774939#39774939) over at StackOverflow. There in my answer I **explain** and **demostrate** code to follow the mouse (so it needs to solve the vector from the current position to the current pointer position), done without any vector library.

Comment: Thanks Theroat. That answer looks very detailed I will study this now so hopefully can understand the maths of this a bit better afterwards

Comment: @Theroat Your answer in the other thread is godlike!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your situation you need a simple subtraction, with a normalization.

```
vectDistance = B - A
vectDirection = vectDistance / lenght(vectDistance)
```

This will give you the direction.

In LibGDX, you can use the [`sub`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector2.html#sub-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2-) method from the `Vector2` class, along with the [`nor`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector2.html#nor--) from the same class:

```
vectDirection = b.sub(a).nor();
```

---

To help figure out if you need to subtract A from B or B from A, try to translate (in your mind) the 'origin' to (0, 0), and move the 'target' along with it. From that perspective, the "direction" should be taken from the position of the 'target'.

Another clue that will make you notice that you used the wrong order: the bullets will fly in the opposite direction of what you're expecting ;P

Comment: i used direction = targetPosition.sub(startPosition); inside my bullets constructor (just in case anyone ever reads this and needs help with same thing)

Comment: Im still having a little trouble implementing this to me game. I have this in my bullet update to move it : setPosition(getX() + direction.x * speed, getX() + direction.y * speed); but with this it works backwards and also only travels either up-right or down-left in diagonal motion only

Comment: i dont think the sub method is what i need. I need the direction Vector expressed as a figure between 0-1.0f,  if you know what i mean

Comment: @SuperMegaBroBro Yes, you need the `sub` method, along with the `nor` method. The `sub` method will give you the vector from A to B. This vector contains 2 things: the direction and the distance. You don't need the distance, so you need to normalize this vector. To do so you use the `nor` method, which will normalize it, i.e. give you a unit vector, i.e. a vector of length 1.

Comment: you're amazing thanks! I was trying it out with 'vector.angle' all last night. will get onto this as soon as home. cheers again :)

Comment: thanks again Alexandre I now have it working. I am gonna post another answer just to show my code as it is quite basic for any beginners like me to view :)

Answer (score 0):

OK thanks to the help of this community (above) Here is actually how I implemented it:

```
  public Bullet(Texture texture, Vector2 startPosition, Vector2 targetPosition){
    super(texture);
    setSize(0.1f,1f);
    setPosition(startPosition.x, startPosition.y);

    direction = targetPosition.sub(startPosition);
    direction.nor();
    System.out.println("direction " + direction.x + "," + direction.y);


}

public void update(float delta){
    setPosition(getX() + (direction.x * speed), getY() + (direction.y * speed));
}
```

This works with the player character standing near the middle of the screen, it will fire bullet anywhere around him that I press. Thanks